# Automattic\WooCommerce connection refused on localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I am trying to create a custom endpoint on wordpress, which would trigger a set of functions. Everything seems to be working till this point where I am trying it on localhost and it refuses to connect. Any advices?

It says:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClientException: cURL Error: Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/nameOfMyPlugin/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php on line 417.

I've tried googling it a lot, but couldn't find anything conclusive

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Automattic\WooCommerce;
$wooCommerceBaseUrl = "http://localhost:8000";
$wooKey= "blablabla";
$wooSecret= "blablablablabla";
$wooCommerceClient = new WooCommerce\Client($wooCommerceBaseUrl,
$wooKey, $wooSecret,
[
    'wp_api' => true,
    'version' => 'wc/v3',
]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `http://localhost:8000` the URL of your WordPress installation?

Seems like the port 8000 is not configured to accept HTTP connections on localhost. Try sending request to port 80, or leave the port and send the request to localhost only.

Comment: it does accept http connections, I tried a simple function to get a list with the existing products on wooCommerce and it works so it must be something else. Any other clue?